# Read Python list from a Text file

Tags: python, list

I recently did a python code execution and on dumping common word from list to .txt file, the execution was failed and exception was caught up in except block. Now I only have the whole list, and copied it to a Text file.

All I want to do is read the list off .txt file and store it inside python list. When I copy all that from .txt, my python stops responding so all I can do is fetch from .txt file.

The list is in this format inside .txt file:

```
['abc.Android.Permission_A', 'abc.Android.Permission_B', .. up to 12000+ words]
```

Comment: if it's all valid python code, `ast.literal_eval` should work.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: You seem to indicate that the contents of the txt file is valid Python literals. `['abc.Android.Permission_A", ... ]`. If that's the case, then you can simply read the file as a string, pass it in to `ast.literal_eval`, and assign the result to some variable. `import ast; contents = ast.literal_eval(f.read())` or etc

Comment: I am getting f is not defined error here

Comment: It seems like you need a general Python tutorial. That's much too broad for StackOverflow. You should absolutely know how to do read and write to files before diving any deeper into the language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you want to use WordPad? It is much simpler with txt files or .py.

Probably this answer should be a comment, because I am not giving you the solution to read lists from a WordPad file, but I don't have enough reputation, so...

**With .py file:**

You can copy the list in a .py file, for example named mylist.py :

```
my_list = ['abc.Android.Permission_A', 'abc.Android.Permission_B', 'abc.Android.Permission_C', etc.. ]
```

And import it in your script:

```
from mylist import my_list
```

Then you can use it as a normal variable.

You can also directly initialize it in your script if your prefer to, in that case you don't need to import anything. The first command would suffice.

**With .txt file**:

```
text_file = open("my_list.txt", "r")
my_list = text_file.read().translate({ord(c): None for c in "[]'"}).split(','))
text_file.close()
```

Or you can use the ast library like Adam Smith mentioned in the comments:

```
import ast; 
text_file = open("my_list.txt", "r")
my_list = ast.literal_eval(text_file.read())
text_file.close()
```

Comment: Well thats the issue I cant copy the list to .py file thats why I want to fetch it somehow to python first from .txt file

Comment: @Arctic97 If you intend to take it from a .txt file, the second option should work. You shoud probably edit your question, specifying that you want to take the list from a .txt file and not from a WordPad file which could have a different format like, for example RTF (Rich Text File)

Comment: The questions appears to me as Text file and not wordpad, as I've edited it mins ago.
But Thank you !!! second option worked much appreciated